# Simple dynamic call graphs in Java

Tags: java, code-analysis, graphviz, callstack

I am looking for a simple dynamic call graph logger for Java that you can add in a few lines of code.   I know there is an [Aspect J solution](http://erik.doernenburg.com/2008/09/call-graph-visualisation-with-aspectj-and-dot/). Also, I helped Zola develop [Glow for C/C++](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~zola/glow/) so I could rewrite a similar tool but I don't want to dig into JVM internals.

Any open source solution out there right now that is stable and better than the AspectJ solution?

The purpose is to use as a companion to unit testing certain portions of the code that you want more information about their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to collect a call *graph* (as opposed to just a set of calls) by any means possible.

One can do with with a static analyzer (if you can get a strong enough one), to collect the potential call graph.  A dynamic method collects one at runtime by instrumenting the code.   Some folks may specifically want the dynamic one, because they want to see the actual call graph for a specific set of input data.

There are several Java profilers that will collect this information dynamically, including [ours](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/JavaProfiler.html).  None of the ones that do that are open source, that I know of, but I could be wrong.

Such profilers often work by instrumenting the code (either source or VM code if the language [e.g., Java,C#] has such).  How they do it depends on the supplier.
In our case, we use our [program transformation tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) to transform the source code from its original form, into a form that also collects profiling data.

You can use AspectJ to insert instrumentation to do this, too. [It is worth noting that aspects are just a special case of program transformation].  Of course, there's more work than just instrumenting the code; you have to collect the runtime data efficiently and after execution process to produce the call graph.  So its rather a bit of work to do all this but you presumably know that from your Glow experience.

Comment: I am more interested in dynamic logging, as I want the edges stored as counters, so I can use the call graph as a Markov chain for something. Glow was actually only a few days of development. GCC has hooks to log function calls. The main hangup was addr2line doesn't work on OSX, and C++ binary compatibility is borked so you have to compile part in C then compile the C++ parts.

Comment: As for doing the dynamic collection it depends on your program. If the function call edges are sparse there won't be quadratic space to store the edges. For each edge it is just a counter (unless you are also logging timestamps) so the complextiy per edge would just be log(#ofCalls).

Comment: Observation: Without function pointer magic (or GOTO outside of a function) the size of the dynamic call graph with counter annotated edges would have an upper bound of O(SizeOfSourceCode*log(Runtime)). Proof: Write an IDE that places a comment above each function call and stores a counter.

Comment: It sounds like you want to track call *sites* as opposed to *calls* between functions.  I observe objects *are* pointers so in effect method calls are calls via function pointers.  The purpose of a dynamic call graph capture is to capture all the function calls (source/target) whether they are statically obvious or not.  If you are willing to settle for only statically obvious function calls, yes, you can preallocate all the needed space and the complexity at runtime can then be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe off-topic, but are you sure you want actually call graph? Somehow I think such a detailed graph will be next to useless in a reasonably sized application. What I find much more useful is a dependency graph between classes, one that is very easy to get as long as you use some kind of dependency injection. I used google guice (and it was actually pretty useful to restructure/keep clean a reasonably sized application).

There is a very nice google-guice-dependency grapher available out-of-the box and for free: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Grapher . I even customized it (extended the Grapher class) to mark different class types with different colors (DAO, controller, API etc.)...

Comment: Partially correct. I intend to do some post processing to get the subgraph of interest. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

There is instrumentation via the native JVMTI C/C++ [native interfaces](http://blog.davber.com/2007/02/07/jvmti-real-time-analysis-of-java-applications/). Like I said I would like to stay in pure Java.

Java does have a Runtime.getRuntime().traceMethodCalls(), but you need something to consume the output still.